# trouble using iup with Lua

Tags: lua, iup

I am trying to get Iup working in Lua.  I have successfully installed and run iup in C, but I have an embedded lua interpreter in my gui and it would be helpful to be able to load dialogs from the interpreter.  however, when I attempt to execute `require("iuplua")`, I get the following error:

```
> require("iuplua")
stdin:1: module 'iuplua' not found:
    no field package.preload['iuplua']
    no file './iuplua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/iuplua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/iuplua/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/iuplua.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/iuplua/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/iuplua.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/iuplua/init.lua'
    no file './iuplua.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/iuplua.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/iuplua.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/iuplua.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

I assume this is because the Lua library for iup is not properly installed.  I attempted to move directly into a directory that contained the `iuplua.lua` file and tried again, and got:

```
> require("iuplua")
./iuplua.lua:6: attempt to index global 'iup' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./iuplua.lua:6: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

which seems to imply errors in the `iuplua.lua` file.  I installed iup by downloading the binaries from sourceforge (I did not compile from source), and installed lua 5.1 (5.1 is required for my project.  please dont recommend and upgrade to 5.2) from the apt repository.  I am running Mint 13.

Any suggestions on resolving these issues are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `package.path` is wrong. Moving into library's folder will only make it worse. Find the library installation path and add it to your `package.path`

Comment: I reset my `package.path` variable to point to the source directory that contains the `iuplua.lua` file, but received the second error above.  any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your Lua configuration must be looking for "iuplua51" files, if not check at the IUP or LuaBinaries documentations on how to set that.

http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/